# JavaFx - Exclude controls from receiving focus

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX application with two text fields, and 6 buttons. Currently, when I hit Tab, it cycles through all of them as expected. But is there any way I can exclude certain buttons from receiving focus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `setFocusTraversable(false);` on each control you don't want to be part of the focus cycle.